# Visual Studio 2012 - MSVCR100D.dll - fix in laymen’s steps

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am running VS 2012 and have opened, it seems, a VS 2010 project.

How do I remove the error ‘missing MSVCR100D.dll’?

I’m pretty new to VS so please explain in laymen’s steps how to do this.

I cannot create another project though, as there are a lot of files linked in the project that for some reason don’t link in a new one.

Thanks

Comment: Layman step #1: pick up the phone and call the owners of these libraries.  Ask for an update.

Comment: Really not helpful. Is there a fix I can do in Visual Studio? It seems even making a new project gives me the same issues with the libraries. Can I rebuild them for VS2012?

Comment: Hi are you trying to build a 64 bit executable on a 32 bit system?

Comment: In addition, is this error stopping you from compiling the project completely? You should be fine to just rebuild the project in 2012 and it will update the debug info/ rebuild dll needed.

Comment: How do I tell whether I'm building a 32 bit application? I'm running a 64 bit OS. And yes, I cannot compile and run the project at all. I've tried cleaning and rebuilding with no luck